# Using Perl regex (PCRE) in awk

Tags: regex, perl, awk, pcre

If I use Perl regex (PCRE) with GNU `grep`, it works pretty well; please consider:

```
$ echo FOO | grep -P '(?i)foo'
FOO
```

I tried PCRE with `awk` but `awk` does not support PCRE.

I only found three different regex modifiers for `awk`/`gawk`

```
--posix
--traditional
--re-interval
```

Does any of the `awk` family use Perl regex (PCRE) like the `grep -P` example above?

Comment: I'm not aware of one — you can create your own `pawk` that includes PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions).  There would be some tricks requird to deal with recognizing and delimiting the more complex REs, but it could be done.  It wouldn't be surprising to find someone's already done it.  OTOH, Perl is distributed with `a2p` to convert `awk` scripts to Perl.  Maybe you should be using that?  Or simply using Perl when you want PCRE?

Comment: `perl` works similar to `awk` when run with the `-n` or `-p` flags, e.g. `seq 100 | perl -ne 'print if /3/'`. See `man perlrun` for details.

Comment: @EdMorton: I agree that writing `pawk` would be painful.  Using `a2p`, you'd use `awk`-recognized regexes in the script to be converted, convert the script, then modify the regexes in the generated code to match the PCRE regexes you really wanted to use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't find `a2p` in Ubuntu (19.10) even if I have perl installed.

Comment: See the [TODO](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/TODO) file of Gawk. Nothing about Perl regex there at the moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, awk does not support Perl REs. One of the primary tenets of the awk language is to keep the language small by not providing constructs to do simple things a bit more briefly. That's how they avoid the language bloat and associated complexity that perl suffers from (see http://www.zoitz.com/archives/13 for the common perception of perl readability). In this case while some of the Perl RE syntax lets you do some things a bit briefer, you don't NEED special language constructs to do them as there's other ways to do whatever you want with existing constructs (maybe not in one RE or using one function so not as briefly) so awk doesn't support them.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I THINK it clearly answers the question of `Do you know if there is species of awk that use the Perl regex like the grep examples above?` and explains why that's the answer.

Comment: There have been so many useful additions to regular expressions in Perl that to try to use existing constructs in awk to try to implement them would be painful, and much harder to read, if it is even possible. ( one such addition is the `(?(DEFINE)...)` construct that contains named subpatterns which can make regular expressions very easy to read. ) I would also like to point out that about half of the comments on the page you linked were positive comments about Perl. I think the real problem is that you think of Perl as just a replacement for awk/bash/sed/grep, when it is so much more.

Comment: @BradGilbert is that why you downvoted or a separate comment? I don't have any real idea of what perl is best suited for. In general I think of it as a tool that you might use instead of a shell script calling various tools but certainly not just the tools awk/sed/grep which are just for text manipulation while perl, I would hope, does a lot more than that or there'd be no point to it existing.

Comment: I didn't see this question until just a few minutes before I posted that comment so it couldn't have been me that downvoted you back on [April 5th](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29454387/timeline). Perl is best suited for everything that you can use Awk, Sed, Bash, Python, Java, or Ruby. All with better Unicode string handling. About the only thing I wouldn't use Perl for is something that really has to be written in C or has to run in the browser. One of my first uses for Perl was sending commands to a dot-matrix printer.

Comment: Still GNU awk (gawk) has some extensions over original AWK language, and its binary file size is multiple of some other implementations'. I do not know how much adding Perl REs would add, but I think it is not an issue, since the size of the binary of GNU Grep is fraction of the size of GNU Awk's binary, and the former supports Perl Regex when using `-P` option.

Comment: On the other hand, binary size of `perl` is multiple of the size of `gawk`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just learn Perl?
Which can do everything you can do in Awk, Sed, and bash. ( and then some )

```bash
$ echo FOO | grep -P '(?i)foo'
FOO

$ echo FOO | perl -ne 'print if /(?i)foo/'
FOO

$ ls /bin /usr/bin | perl -lnE '$p{$_}++ if /(grep|sed|awk)$/; END { say for sort keys %p }'
awk
bzegrep
bzfgrep
bzgrep
dgawk
egrep
fgrep
gawk
grep
igawk
list-unreleased
lzegrep
lzfgrep
lzgrep
mawk
msggrep
nawk
pgawk
pgrep
psed
ptargrep
rgrep
sed
xzegrep
xzfgrep
xzgrep
zegrep
zfgrep
zgrep
zipgrep
```

```perl
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use v5.12.0; # sets minimum version adds `say`, and does `use strict`
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions qw' path catfile splitpath ';

my %cmds;

# go through all directories in `$PATH` or `%PATH%`
# in a platform independent way
for my $dir_path ( path ){

  # a quick hack that is good enough for now
  for my $cmd_path ( glob catfile $dir_path, '*grep' ){

    # only need the filename, so assign everything else
    # to `undef`
    my ( undef, undef, $cmd ) = splitpath $cmd_path;

    # store it in an array in the %cmds hash
    push @{ $cmds{$cmd} }, $cmd_path;
  }
}

for my $cmd ( sort keys %cmds ) {
  say $cmd, ' :';

  # the actual locations of the program or symlink
  say ' 'x4, $_ for @{ $cmds{$cmd} };
}
```

```bash
bzegrep :
    /bin/bzegrep
bzfgrep :
    /bin/bzfgrep
bzgrep :
    /bin/bzgrep
egrep :
    /bin/egrep
fgrep :
    /bin/fgrep
grep :
    /bin/grep
lzegrep :
    /usr/bin/lzegrep
lzfgrep :
    /usr/bin/lzfgrep
lzgrep :
    /usr/bin/lzgrep
msggrep :
    /usr/bin/msggrep
pgrep :
    /usr/bin/pgrep
ptargrep :
    /opt/perl/bin/ptargrep
    /usr/bin/ptargrep
rgrep :
    /usr/bin/rgrep
xzegrep :
    /usr/bin/xzegrep
xzfgrep :
    /usr/bin/xzfgrep
xzgrep :
    /usr/bin/xzgrep
zegrep :
    /bin/zegrep
zfgrep :
    /bin/zfgrep
zgrep :
    /bin/zgrep
zipgrep :
    /usr/bin/zipgrep
```

I would like to point out the reason I have `ptargrep` in there twice is that I maintain my own versions of Perl with one of them symlinked from `/opt/perl/bin`, and `ptargrep` is a Perl program that installs with the [Archive::Tar](https://metacpan.org/release/Archive-Tar) module.

This example doesn't even use any of the cool new features added to Perl since 2010 when 5.12.0 was released.
( Perl now has a yearly release cycle )

Of course you could also use Perl to create a website like [Lacuna Expanse](http://www.lacunaexpanse.com/), or to write a video game like [Frozen Bubble](http://www.frozen-bubble.org/).

---

There is also a new language called Perl 6 which I find even more fun to use.
The plan is for there to be a full release sometime this year.

Comment: Perl 6 is now called [Raku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raku_(programming_language)). Why learn Perl, if Raku is better? Either of them might be overkill, if you just need more advanced regex.

Comment: [Some quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Future-Extensions) (Larry Wall is the creator of Perl.)

Comment: @jarno If you want to learn a language specifically for only minimal text alterations then awk would be fine. The question is what if you need to also do more advanced things? Perl is about the same for one-liners as awk, but it also works for large systems.

Comment: Well, I know AWK already. Raku seems interesting not only for its regex features, but it has also taken influences of some other languages besides Perl. On the other hand, I do not know Python, either.